# bash script works really slow after updating Mac OS from Mojave to Big Sur

Tags: bash, c++, macos-bigsur

Yesterday I updated my MacBook Pro Mid 2015 from Mac OS Mojave to Mac OS Big Sur, and today I have noticed that my bash script for stress-testing C++ programs works really slow. My script runs this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10000}; do
    echo "test $i"
    ./$3 > input
    ./$1 < input > wrong
    ./$2 < input > correct
    cmp --silent correct wrong || break
done

cat input
echo "correct :"
cat correct
echo "wrong :"
cat wrong
```

I ran this code with C++ programs that output 1 and even then it was slow.
I have no clue about what is wrong, but before I updated my system this exact code worked like 10 times faster. I compile my C++ code using this string:

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -DLOCAL -O2 -Wshadow -Wconversion -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=bounds $1.cpp -o $1
```

Is there a way to make this script faster?

UPD: My friend suggested running this script without any warning/sanitize options in my compilation string, and this is what I got:

```
# warnings & sanitizers are on
Olerinskiy:~ yan$ time ./a

real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.051s

# warnings & sanitizers are off
Olerinskiy:~ yan$ time ./a

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Is this ok? Looks like this was the problem, but I don't remember it taking so much time before the update.

Comment: There was a change of default shells between Mojave and Catalina - macOS shifted to zsh between these two releases. I don't know if it would fix your problem (as I don't have the right environment to test it out) but you could try using ports to install the latest version of bash. Install mac ports then `sudo port install bash` then change the shebang on your script to point to the ports version of bash.

Comment: What is the output of `type /bin/bash` on your system?

Comment: @Mark `/bin/bash is /bin/bash`

Comment: @Mark I did what you suggested, installed bash and changed the shebang to `#!/opt/local/bin/bash` (I am still not sure, but this looks like the path I need), and nothing really changed :(
Thanks for trying though, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Break the script down into individual parts and run each part with the `time` command to see how long each step takes on your new and your old system to identify which bit is taking longer. (`man time` if you need to find out how the time command works)

Comment: Since Catalina, macOS sends a checksum if every program the first time it runs to Apple's servers. Could this be the reason? To test, disconnect from Ethernet/Wi-Fi and try your script.

Comment: @At0mic didn't help :(

Comment: @Mark I don't have my old system anymore. Is it possible to do this some other way?

Comment: You could run the time command on each step (or multiple iterations of each step) to see where the bottleneck is

Comment: There was this issue (https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/11/macos-big-sur-launch-appears-to-cause-temporary-slowdown-in-even-non-big-sur-macs/ and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25074959) which affected performance a lot.